# Conditional set argument in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform

I have a task which I want to define a set argument, depending on the value of the variable, which is diferent in each terraform workspace. My code:

```
resource "helm_release" "external-dns" {

  name       = local.external-dns-name
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "external-dns"
  namespace  = local.external-dns-namespace

  set {
    name = "extraArgs.aws-assume-role"
    value = var.assume_dns[terraform.workspace]
  }
}
```

Depending on the AWS account I'm deploying the var is diferent, because the DNS creation is managed by the PRE account (route53) , so when I'm deploying in all the accounts I have to use the assume-role annotation, except in the PRE account.

```
assume_dns = {
    platform = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/external-eks-api"
    pre = "null"
    dev = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/external-dns-eks-api"
    prod = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/external-dns-eks-api"
}
```

So I would need an exception to this account, I've tried to define as null as I read in some documentation, but it doesn't work.. Any idea of how to get this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html?

Comment: I think I can't use this kind of conditionals in a 'set'. thx anyway

Comment: First, `null` should not have quotes. You are passing a 4 character string, not an empty/null value. Second, to make a block inside a resource conditional, you have to make it a [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html).